# dplyr-error when using count()

Tags: r, count, dplyr, plyr, tidyverse

When I execute the following code:

```
merged <- interrogations %>% 
             filter(person=='accused') %>% 
             count(caseId)
```

I get an error:

```
#Error in count(., caseId) : object 'caseId' not found
```

But then, when I look it up with `interrogations$caseId` the variable `interrogations$caseId` **does** actually exist. What am I doing wrong?

The variable names are in german, but I hope this helps anyway (interrogations=einvernahmen):

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, person = c("Beschuldigter", "Auskunftsperson", 
"Beschuldigter", "Auskunftsperson", "Beschuldigter", "Beschuldigter"
), behoerde = c("Pol", "Pol", "Pol", "Pol", "Pol", "Pol"), datum = c("10.05.2013", 
"29.04.2013", "10.05.2013", "06.04.2013", "15.05.2013", "10.05.2013"
), anwBesch = c("ja", "nein", "ja", "nein", "ja", "ja"), anwVert =  c("ja", 
"nein", "ja", "nein", "ja", "ja"), verhalten = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", "Bestreiten", "Geständnis", 
"Schweigen", "Teilgeständnis"), class = "factor"), caseId = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), user = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), 
dokuAussage = c("2", "", "2", "1", "2", "2"), dokuAussageAnd = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), uebersetzer = c("", "", "", "", "", 
""), offenEinv = c("", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("id", 
"person", "behoerde", "datum", "anwBesch", "anwVert", "verhalten", 
"caseId", "user", "dokuAussage", "dokuAussageAnd", "uebersetzer", 
"offenEinv"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide some of your data with `dput(head(interrogations))` to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: I don't get an error, which version of R and dplyr are you running?

Comment: It's R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) and dplyr 0.7.4

Comment: No error here either. But `filter(...)` returns an empty `tibble`.

Comment: `library(dplyr)
test<-data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c"))
tib<-as_tibble(test)
tib %>% count(a)`   does return the same error, therefore filter() cannot be the problem. it's pretty strange..

Comment: Try `dplyr::count(caseId)`. It's likely to be a package conflict with `plyr`.

Comment: `interrogations %>% filter(person=='Auskunftsperson') %>% count(caseId)`. There is no `accused` in your `person` variable in the provided data. `table(interrogations$person)` gives `Auskunftsperson` and   `Beschuldigter`.

Comment: Thank you guys, that seems to have solved the problem! (package conflict)

Answer (score 0):

```
interrogations %>% 
   filter(person == 'Auskunftsperson') %>% 
   count(caseId)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  caseId     n
   <int> <int>
1      7     2


interrogations %>% 
   group_by(person) %>% 
   summarise(freq = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  person           freq
  <chr>           <int>
1 Auskunftsperson     2
2 Beschuldigter       4
```

Comment: Works for me. The only thing I could think of is that the data your sampled for your question differs from the dataset you're working it. Perhaps double check your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I also just came across this error and luckily I was able to trace it back to loading the Rmisc package. To those of the future that hit this problem, try restarting your R session, reloading all packages except Rmisc and running it again.